# Is there any way to provide tk_messagebox an input from TCL itself and not by the click of button by user?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a condition that triggers a tk_messageBox. Now, after staying for a period of let's say 10 seconds, I want it to disappear with an "ok" input without any click or interaction from the user. Is there a way that can be done?

```
        if {condition is matched} {
          set input [tk_messageBox -message $message -icon <iconType> -type <messageBoxType>]
         }
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30237061/1578604). Seems like it's not possible, but you can create your own message box (using [`toplevel`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/toplevel.htm) and whatnot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard message box does not support that, as the underlying OS dialog on at least one platform (can't remember if it is Windows or macOS) doesn't support such a thing.

But you can get access to the scripted version of the dialog (which is the default one on Linux) and inject the trigger:

```
# Set up the timeout; I got the widget name by reading the sources
set handle [after 10000 .__tk__messagebox.no invoke]

# This is the internal name of the implementation
set answer [tk::MessageBox -type yesno -message "Foo"]

# Make sure we clear our timeout in case the user *did* pick something
after cancel $handle
```

Different message box types have different names for the (final part of the name of the) default button, but they'll be one of `ok`, `cancel`, `no` or `abort`, depending on dialog type. It should be obvious which. (Alternatively, just destroy the `.__tk_messagebox` window. I *think* that also picks the default.)

Answer (score 1):

This is another possible solution using toplevel:

```
set message "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

if {condition is matched} {
    toplevel .new_window

    wm title      .new_window "Window title"
    wm geometry   .new_window 320x100
    wm minsize    .new_window 320 100
    wm maxsize    .new_window 320 100
    wm protocol   .new_window WM_DELETE_WINDOW {destroy .new_window}
    wm attributes .new_window -topmost yes

    set input -1

    pack [label .new_window.message -text $message] -fill none -expand 1
    pack [frame .new_window.buttons] -fill none -expand 1

    pack [ttk::button .new_window.buttons.button1 -text "OK" -command {
        set input 1
        destroy .new_window
    }] -side left -padx 5

    pack [ttk::button .new_window.buttons.button2 -text "Cancel" -command {
        set input 0
        destroy .new_window
    }] -side right -padx 5

    after 10000 {
        if {[winfo exists .new_window]} {
            destroy .new_window
            if {$input == -1} {
                set input 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The variable **$input** holds the user input value (0 or 1), after a timeout of ten seconds without a click the window will self-close with deafult value of 1 (ok).

Pay attention however, before the click or until the timeout expires the variable **$input** has the value of -1

EDIT: to avoid the latter uncertain behavior you'll probably want this:

```
set message "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

if {condition is matched} {
    toplevel .new_window

    wm title      .new_window "Window title"
    wm geometry   .new_window 320x100
    wm minsize    .new_window 320 100
    wm maxsize    .new_window 320 100
    wm protocol   .new_window WM_DELETE_WINDOW {
        set input 1
        destroy .new_window
    }
    wm attributes .new_window -topmost yes

    if {[info exists input]} {
        unset input
    }

    pack [label .new_window.message -text $message] -fill none -expand 1
    pack [frame .new_window.buttons] -fill none -expand 1

    pack [ttk::button .new_window.buttons.button1 -text "OK" -command {
        set input 1
        destroy .new_window
    }] -side left -padx 5

    pack [ttk::button .new_window.buttons.button2 -text "Cancel" -command {
        set input 0
        destroy .new_window
    }] -side right -padx 5

    after 10000 {
        if {[winfo exists .new_window]} {
            set input 1
            destroy .new_window}
        }
    }
    vwait input
}
```

To pause execution waiting for user input or the dafault answer.

Bye

Comment: Thanks for such detailed help. I appreciate that. :)